# more than one value option from radio button for insert into database

Tags: php

This is the coding for the radio buttons, my problem is, I've tried to run this coding. but, at first only in a1 only to the database. when I add the option for b1, the value not insert into database. how can I make other choices if  only  value a1  that can go into the database. i have 10 option to be insert into mysql

```
      <?php
require_once "connection.php";
    $conn = connect();
    $db = connectdb();

mysql_select_db($db,$conn) or die (mysqli_error() . "\n");
$query_usr = "select * from penilaian";
$usr = mysql_query($query_usr,$conn) or die(mysql_error()."\n".$query_usr);
$row_usr=mysql_fetch_assoc($usr);


$a1=$_REQUEST['a1'];
$b1=$_REQUEST['b1'];


echo $query ="insert into penilaian (a1,b1) values($a1,$b1)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "testing".$result;
echo "<script languange = 'Javascript'>
                alert('Terima Kasih ! Penilaian anda sudah diterima ');
                location.href = 'home.php';</script>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a radio button can **only** have one value. If you want to pass multiple values for a particular input, use a `select` input with the `multiple` attribute set, or create additional radio buttons. If you have a more specific problem/question, post your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you better take the name attribute in radio button in an array because you have to select only one radio out of all Like

```
<input type="radio" name='a[]' value='1' />
<input type="radio" name='a[]' value='2' />
................ more -----------------------
```

then

```
$a = $_REQUEST['a'][0];
```